# Update Query with inner join ....?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I have this Table Named SubscriptionCharity, and its as the following :

```
SubscriptionId       ChannelURI       CharUserID
1                       AX                12
2                       ZA                7
3                       AX                10
```

I want to to check for a specfic CharUserId if any record in the table with the same channel uri and set it to null , so in this table "Subcriptionid =1 " should be set to null

I have two queries for this , one works in MS SQL Managment m but doesn't work with LINQ :
(it doesn't affect the rows )

```
UPDATE SubscriptionCharProg 
Set ChannelURI = null 
FROM SubscriptionCharProg as t1
INNER JOIN SubscriptionCharProg as t2 
    on t1.ChannelURI = t2.ChannelURI 
    and t1.DeviceId = t2.DeviceId 
WHERE CharUserId! = 5
```

and Another One that works for LINQ but not with MS SQL Managment :
(MS SQL Managment Error : Invalid Object Name "t1")

```
context.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE t1 Set t1.ChannelURI = 1 FROM SubscriptionCharProg as t1 INNER JOIN  
  SubscriptionCharProg as t2 on t1.ChannelURI = t2.ChannelURI WHERE t1.CharUserId! = " 
  + charuserID + "", null);
```

Also , the main problem is , both queries nulls every channelURi Whether its equal or not

Any ideas please?

Edit : in case if the a record with a specific charuserID is exist twice or more it keeps and doesn't set it to null

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line from:

```
UPDATE SubscriptionCharProg
```

to

```
UPDATE t1
```

Comment: done, linq gives the error : charuserid is ambiguous , MS management gives the error : cannot update charuserid

Comment: `context.ExecuteStoreCommand(...)` isn't really LINQ to SQL (I was assuming that meant a LINQ to SQL operation), but I think you should try using `context.ExecuteCommand(...)` instead.

Comment: still having the intial problem which it nulls all rows in the channeluri column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET ChannelURI = null 
FROM SubscriptionCharProg as t1
INNER JOIN SubscriptionCharProg as t2 
    on t1.ChannelURI = t2.ChannelURI 
    and t1.DeviceId = t2.DeviceId 
    and t1.CharUserID <> t2.CharUserID
WHERE t2.CharUserID = 5
```

Comment: I want to check on the same table for a Specific CharUserID if there is another CharUSerID with the same ChannelURI then set it to null,sorry about the deviceId column

Comment: Ahh ok I see, I've just updated the query to reflect that.  Give that a shot.

Comment: I just recreated your exact table, inserted your  example data and ran my query and it worked as expected in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio without any error. Did you copy and paste the query exactly? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: yes , I did , I'm using server explorer in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

```
update quiz_subgroup as sg  

inner join (select qq_qsg_id, count(qq_id) as cnt_ques from quiz_questions group by qq_qsg_id) as ques on(ques.qq_qsg_id = sg.qsg_id) 

set sg.qsg_count_of_questions = ques.cnt_ques;
```